# Sizing images in fixed-size-div

Tags: html, css, image

I created a gallery with grid layout having cells with size 285x285 pixels.
I need to populate the gallery with images of diverse dimensions, including: 285x285, 290x285, 100x200, 500x800 and so on.

My gallery is supposed to work as follow:

- if the image is bigger than 285x285, get the center-top portion of it
  with size 285x285
- if the image is smaller than 285x285, stretch the
  **SMALLER** dimension to 285px and get the center-top portion of it with size 285x285, but keep the original image ratio

This way, I want to fill up the entire cell space with no white holes in the grid, except for some margin between cells (5px right and 5px bottom).

I tried the following css:

```
.imagegallery {
    padding: 2px !important;
    background-position:50% 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height:285px;
    min-width:285px;
    max-height:285px;
    max-width:285px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

However, the results is the following:

- if image is larger than 285x285, I correctly get the portion of the image I want (center top)
- if the image is smaller than 285x285, the **LARGER** dimension is stretched to 285px and the original image ratio is kept

This way, sometimes I get some white space around the images that are smaller than 285x285 in at least one dimension.

How do I fill up the white space via css?

====UPDATE====

I am using Bootstrap.

HTML example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 portfolio-item img-list imagegallery" 
         style="background-image:url('./images/img.jpg');>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`background-image:url` is in style, rather than class, as the image name is built via AngularJS.

Comment: Please show the HTML of a single instance, with its nearest parents ...

Comment: OP updated to include the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the updated html, use the "background-size" property. With browser prefixes, this is probably the best CSS-Only solution. Also, you are missing a closing quotation for your "style" attribute.

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Do I need to remove any other css property from the ones I've already put? This way, it seems I get the image deformed, which I don't want to.

Comment: I assigned 285px 285px as background-size value

Comment: Ok, if I assign cover as value, it does not seem to deform the image. Thanks.

Comment: I would typically use "cover". Which stretches the image to fit the space without changing the aspect ratio (distorting). It does this by "zooming" into the center of the image and hiding the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `object-fit:cover` property. This will cover the image area proportionately without stretching smaller dimensions.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: object-fit isn’t widely supported yet ... notably not by IE.

Comment: I tried to add it to imagegallery, but that doesn't seem to work. I updated my OP to include some HTML.